# Phaser 2 - Uncaught TypeError: this.state is undefined

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I am trying to deploy an old project that was working fine but now I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state is undefined

The error is at the lines:

```
resetPlayer:function(){   
audioHurt.play();   player.reset(100,300);    
health-- ;

if (health < 1) {       music.destroy();    
this.state.start('GameOver');   } 
}
```

And the state was already added in the index.html file:

```
game.state.add('GameOver', Game.GameOver);
```

Any idea why this is happening now?

Comment: In which `function`/callback is the code snippet called?

Comment: It is called in a function to reset player when it loses 3 lives - game over:

`resetPlayer:function(){
  audioHurt.play();
  player.reset(100,300);

  health-- ;

  if (health < 1) {
      music.destroy();
      this.state.start('GameOver');
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

To give an exact answer you would need to share more code, but it seems that this has to do with missing context for `this`.

if you are executing `resetPlayer` in a callback from a collision like this:

```
 game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite1, sprite2, collisionCallback, processCallback, this);
```

don't forget to pass the `this` context into the function call. Check if the `state` property is bound to the current `this` reference.

> ***Disclaimer:** I'm not so proficient with Phaser CE, but this javascript error message suggest a context issue.*